# Div moves when resize window

Tags: html, resize

Hi I am really struggling with this, can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I am building my friends website: [bethcalter.co.uk/index.php](http://bethcalter.co.uk/index.php) and when checking it on other browsers, the divs were off the page and when I resized the window the divs were moving and I don't want them to do that.

I am new to HTML/CSS I don't do a lot of it, I'm more a designer, please help, I have looked for answers on here already, but something is up with my coding I think, I have tried giving the divs their own wrapper etc and it doesnt work.

**My css:**

```
#content {
    margin:0;
    width:900px;
    height:400px;
    margin-left:360px;
    margin-top:-930px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    position:absolute;
}

#bar {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:900px;
    height:90px;
    margin-left:360px;
    margin-top:-1010px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    opacity: 0.4;
    position:absolute;

}
```

**Html:**

```
<body>
  <div id="banner">
  </div>
  <div id="background">
    <div id="wrapper">
      <img src="images/Statue4.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="wrap">
    <div id="bar">
    </div>
    <div id="content">
      <img src='images/deb.jpg' style="margin: 40px 40px 40px 40px"/>
    </div>
  </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Please help, much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Your big image div is moving if you resize your window because your are aligning it to the center of the page.

Remove this line in your css in your #wrapper selector if you just want to have it aligned left:

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

Comment: The big image needs to be centered, thats the design, I removed the code and its fixed the problem, But the big image needs to be centered.

Comment: ok. I think it would be more logical to set a background image to `#wrap`. but If you want to keep the `<img>` as you background, you should move `<div id="wrap"> ... </div>` (and all of its contents) inside `<div id="wrapper"> ... </div>` then set `#wrapper { position: relative; }` and then get rid of the ridiculously high margins in `#content`

Comment: I've done that, but I need the div containers to be central too over the big background image. Thanks for your help btw

Comment: just add `#wrapper { margin: 0 auto; }` again ;) and remove any other margins you have set to `#wrapper`

Comment: oh, and to center the inner divs add this:
`#bar { left: 95px; }`
`#content { left: 95px; }`